# After change of Android SDK version 33 suggestion not work in xml layout file

Tags: android, xml

I have change **targetSdkVersion 33** and **compileSdkVersion 33** then current code in layout file suggestion not working. I have try with cntrl+space but not working. Like i have added one button in layout and I want to define text or text color size etc. Property from xml code. but not get suggestion for example **android:text**

```
 compileSdkVersion 33
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

  buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

See below image for more understanding
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what file suggestion is not working? Provide more data please.

Comment: @tomerpacific please check updated question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem after migration to the 33 SDK version.
It's a bug in **Android Studio Chipmunk**, this [issue in Google tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460885).
They fixed it for **Android Studio Dolphin**, it's in the beta still but you can use it if it's not critical for you, otherwise, you need to roll back to the 32 SDK version because it seems it won't be fixed in the Chipmunk now.

[image]

**UPD:** **[News](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/09/android-studio-dolphin.html)!** **Android Studio Dolphin** is stable now, feel free to upgrade.

Comment: I just upgraded to dolphin and the XML autocomplete isn't still working

Answer (score 0):

> **This solution is related to the Android Studio Dolphin Version**

After alot of searching and testing, I upgraded my gradle version and its work for me.

Just goto `File -> Project Structure` or press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` and then `upgrate the gradle version` as shown in the image below and then `invalidate cache and restart` the Android Studio and its working

[image]

As shown in the image I upgrade my gradle

Happy Coding With Android Studio :)