# Xml Suggestions not getting after change compileSdk & targetSdk to 33

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I am getting some issue while updating compilesdk and targetsdk to 33.

And if I set compilesdk or targetsdk to 32, 31 or less, I get another library support issue during compilation, as described below...

```
 1.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
  depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
  Android APIs.

  :app is currently compiled against android-32.

  Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
  plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

  Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
  plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use
  compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

  Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
  allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
  targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
  minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
  on).
```

and getting this same issue with all newly added library to the gradle

I'm not sure if this is a sdk 33 or library issue.

I already tried this--->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries/54007742#54007742

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505543). There is issue in Android Studio Chipmunk Version. Google Team fixed in Android Studio Dolphin. Check [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235792434) as well

Comment: I just upgraded to dolphin and I'm still having this same bug

Comment: Wow, Android Studio Chipmunk wont autocomplete in xml and Dolphin wont show xml preview. This is disaster.

Comment: And Flamingo works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.6.0-alpha02"
```

with

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-rc01"
```

in `build.gradle(app)` file.
Please refer to [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbamn.png) for screenshot.